# Use Ctrl + Left/Right to move forward/back one word in tmux within Mobaxterm

Tags: bash, tmux

When using tmux within Mobaxterm, Ctrl + Left/Right just moves the cursor forward/back one character, not one word.

In the following cases, Ctrl + Left/Right does behave as expected:

- in bash within Mobaxterm
- in screen within Mobaxterm
- in tmux within Cygwin
- in screen or bash within Cygwin

So it seems to be an issue only when combining tmux with Mobaxterm.

In all cases, I am ssh-ing to a remote linux machine, within either Cygwin or Mobaxterm. My /etc/inputrc is set as it should for the shortcuts to work.

Any clue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Old question. But in case someone find his way here. This is sgzmd's answer:

Edit your ~/.tmux.conf and add lines:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

If you don’t want to make it permanent just yet, do:

```
C-b :set-window-option xterm-keys on
```

Reload your config in tmux by doing:

```
C-b :source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

It worked for me.

original answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/360832/how-can-i-make-ctrlleft-right-keys-work-right-in-tmux)

Comment: This fixed the behavior in bash, but to also get the shortcuts to work under emacs in tmux, I had to use Kieran Moore's answer in the original answer you referred to:
`set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`

Comment: This didn;t work for me on macos. I am sshing into a remote mac, and Meta left/right prints ;3D ;#C

Comment: To use ctrl + arrow inside tmux and Windows Terminal add `set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to ~/.tmux.conf